# Add multipage caption by looping from cell values

Tags: vba, excel, userform, multipage, do-loops

I would like to generate the captions for the pages of an userform multipage by looping through some cell values, but unfortunately i get an error when the userform is initialized.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim pagecount As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim name As Integer

pagecount = Sheets("SETUP").Range("B" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 5
n = 0
name = 6

With MultiPage1
Do
.Pages(n).Caption = Sheets("SETUP").Range("B" & name).Value
n = n + 1
name = name + 1
Loop Until n = pagecount
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `i get an error` - what error? in what line?

Comment: In no line. It's a runtime error '5'. 'Invalid procedure call or argument'. Thanks!

Comment: it's because number of pages and `pagecount` doesn't match. Maybe you need something like this:  `If n>=.Pages.Count Then .Pages.Add` just after `Do` line?

Comment: Oh okay, thanks to simoco, i found the solution (Needed to add a page before caption it.):

    With MultiPage1
    Do
    .Pages.Add.Caption = Sheets("SETUP").Range("B" & name).Value
    n = n + 1
    name = name + 1
    Loop Until n = pagecount
    End With

It was a pretty dumb question afterall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this one works:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim pagecount As Long
    Dim n As Long

    pagecount = Sheets("SETUP").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 5
    n = 0

    With MultiPage1
        Do
            If n >= .Pages.Count Then .Pages.Add
            .Pages(n).Caption = Sheets("SETUP").Range("B" & n + 6).Value
            n = n + 1
        Loop Until n = pagecount
    End With
End Sub
```

Also note, that I've changed `Dim pagecount As Integer` to `Dim pagecount As Long` (because max value of integer is only `32768`). For your example it's unlikely to have more than `32768` pages, but in general it's a good practise to use `Long` when determining last row.